# Does reducing message history on one device affect other devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, history

If I have one apple account signed into multiple devices, and I change the iMessage message history from **Forever** to **30 Days** on one device, will this have *any impact* on any other devices with this same apple account?

[image]
I'm just trying to make sure I don't delete older messages on any other devices when deleting older messages on the one device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not. Each holds messages it received from the servers irrespective of other devices.